# Is it possible to override the "Invalid Value" event in PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

When you input the wrong value for a property in a propertyGrid, say: put a letter where a number should be, then change focus or press enter, a message box pops up informing you that this is not the type of data expected, and forces you to change it before leaving that property. This behavior is built into the propertyGrid.

What I'd like to do is override this behavior so that I can handle it myself in the "OnPropertyValueChanged" event.

Comment: Not really.  This behavior is built into the TypeConverter for the type of the property you are editing.  Its ConvertFromString() throws an exception, the PropertyGrid merely displays it.  Replacing type converters has rapidly diminishing returns, PropertyGrid is only good enough for simple editing tasks.

Comment: So you're saying there's a way to replace the TypeConverter?